# Concatenate a string with integer in loop to convert columns to factor

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I need convert some columns of my dataset and I wish create a loop to do this instead of type line to line. But compiler show error.

**Do this loop**

```
for (i in dados_full[, 'id.' + length(12:38)]){
+   dados_full = factor(dados_full[, 'id.'+ i])
+   i =+ 1
+ }
Error in "id." + length(12:38) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**Instead of**

```
dados_full[,"id.13"] = factor(dados_full[,"id.13"]) 
dados_full[,"id.14"] = factor(dados_full[,"id.14"]) 
dados_full[,"id.15"] = factor(dados_full[,"id.15"])
dados_full[,"id.16"] = factor(dados_full[,"id.16"]) 
dados_full[,"id.17"] = factor(dados_full[,"id.17"])
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `lapply` to loop over the columns and convert to `factor`

```
nm1 <- paste0("id.", 13:17)
dados_full[nm1] <- lapply(dados_full, factor)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dados_full <- dados_full %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('id.'), factor))
```

---

In the OP's code, the `+` is used for `paste`ing, but it wouldn't work in `R`.  We need `paste` as `operator+` overloading is not a case in `R`

```
nm1 <- paste("id.", 12:38)
for (nm in nm1){
   dados_full[[nm]] <-  factor(dados_full[[nm]])
  
 }
```